# Git rebase --onto rebased branch

Tags: git, rebase, git-commit

I need some help on how to use `git rebase --onto` to rebase a working branch effectively. I tried to follow this doc https://womanonrails.com/git-rebase-onto

### Context

I branched `branch-B` from `branch-A`. In the meantime `branch-A` was rebased on main, so does `branch-B`.

```
Old situation                         Current situation (after two rebase)
A---B---C---F---G (origin/main)       A---B---C---F---G (origin/main)
         \                                            | \
          D---E---H (branch-A)                        |  D'---E'---H' (branch-A)
                  \                                    \ 
                   J---K (branch-B)                     J'---K' (branch-B)
```

### Expected result

I want to rebranch `branch-B` on `branch-A` without the pain of resolving each previous commits except eventually `J` and `K`

```
Expected result                                   
A---B---C---F---G (origin/main)
                  \
                   D'---E'---H' (branch-A)
                              \ 
                               J'---K' (branch-B)
```

This is what I tried so far

```bash
git checkout branch-B
git rebase branch-A --onto origin/main
```

Thanks !

Comment: What was wrong with what you have tried?

Comment: Do you mean that you are looking for `git rebase --onto branch-A origin/main branch-B`?

Comment: With these commands I need to resolve conflicts for each commits, I'm expecting a smooth resolution : D and D' are the same changes, E and E' too... etc

Comment: I don't think you can avoid resolving conflicts if there are any.

Comment: I meant that there should'nt be any conflicts to resolve, I'm expecting a smooth resolution. Each commands I tried (yours included) ask me to resolve conflicts from the first commit and all others after... :/

Comment: So your question is why there are conflicts?

Comment: Yes, as the contents of the commits are the same and `J` `K` are new commits from `branch-A` POV, there shouldn't be any conflicts. So I'm suspecting that the command isn't working well

Comment: Have you tried to use the command I mentioned instead?

Comment: Yes sure, on a sample example it worked as expected, but not on my case.

I believe I will simply cherry pick the new commits on `branch-B` into a new branch from `branch-A`

Comment: That's fundamentally what rebase does, as well.

Comment: If the schema of the current and expected are accurate, the 'rebase' and 'rebase --onto' command will do exactly the same thing. As a consequence, if you have conflicts with one, you will have the exact sames with the other one. For me, starting from the old situation is even better. You even have a new rebase parameter to rebase both branches at the same time: `--update-refs` https://github.blog/2022-10-03-highlights-from-git-2-38/#rebase-dependent-branches-with-update-refs

Comment: If I understand correctly, after `branch-a` was rebased, the rebase of `branch-b` is yet to take place, right? Well, you need to run `git rebase --onto origin/main old-position-of-branch-a branch-b` .... or specify the last commit from _old_ `branch-a` in your `branch-b`... like ``git rebase onto origin/main last-commit-of-branch-a-in-branch-b branch-b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, starting from the chart on the right in the first square, you can do this:

```
git checkout branch-b
git rebase branch-a
```

WHich would produce

```
A---B---C---F---G (origin/main)
         \
          D'---E'---H' (branch-A)
                     \ 
                      J'---K' (branch-B)
```

So... let me explain a little bit what's going on with `--onto`. When the rebase of `branch-a` took place, you ended up with this:

```
A---B---C---F---G <- (origin/main)
         \       \
          \       D'--E'--H' <- (branch-a)
           \
            D---E---H--J---K <- (branch-B)
```

Notice how *the original* commits that made up `branch-a` are still there as part of the history of `branch-b`. So, if you ran `git checkout branch-b; git rebase branch-a`, git would rebase commits starting on the last *common* ancestor of `branch-a` (**current**) and `branchg-b`... and what commit is that? It's definitely **not** `H` (the previous tip of `branch-a`), it would be `C`... and then the rebase would try to apply `C..K`... on top of `branch-a`.... which is **not** correct... what you would like to rebase would be `H..K`... and that would need this to be run: `git rebase --onto branch-a H branch-b`, which would apply `H..K` on `branch-a`, which is what we want.